# Knapsack for Extremely Large Inputs

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

I've implemented my solution to the problem according to the pseudocode on Wikipedia. I used a multidimensional array to store the solution for item I and capacity K. However, this fails for extremely large inputs. I run out of heap space. Any suggestions as to how to optimize?

```
int[][] optimal = new int[items][capacity];
boolean[][] solution = new boolean[items][capacity];
```

Fails when:

```
items = 10000;
capacity = 1000001;
```

Comment: If you posted some code, specifically the part that's failing with large inputs, we would be much more able to help.

Comment: increase your heap maybe the correct answer.